# OneHotEncoder get_dummies() for 4 columns

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Have DataFrame like: columns

> ['team_1_player1', 'team_1_player2', 'team_2_player1', 'team_2_player2']

Players represented by their ID. like

> [1, 2, 3, 4]

I whant to make  DataFrame with this columns

> ['team_1_id_1', 'team_2_id_1', 'team_1_id_2', 'team_2_id_2', 
>    'team_1_id_3', 'team_2_id_3', 'team_1_id_4', 'team_2_id_4']

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109779/running-get-dummies-on-several-dataframe-columns does this answer your question?

Comment: @TH14 Thanks. it works!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109779/running-get-dummies-on-several-dataframe-columns

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of the linked question that worked. [Running get\_dummies on several DataFrame columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109779/running-get-dummies-on-several-dataframe-columns)